# Predict stereochemistry of product

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

[image: 3-methyl(1,1-2H2)pent-1-ene]

When 3-methyl(1,1-<sup>2</sup>H<sub>2</sub>)pent-1-ene reacts with HCl, why do we obtain a racemic mixture?
The given reactant is optically pure.

Comment: That fully depends on whether the starting material is racemic.

Comment: I have made the edit.

Comment: Actually, I lied, it depends on more on the product you obtain. And looking at this again, there's a good chance that you will access an intermediate that scrambles the starting material's stereochemistry.

Comment: What is the product you expect? I think the CH group will form a new stereo center.
I think if you protonate your doublebond, you will end up with a CH+ carbocation. The Cl- has no steric preference wheather it comes from the top or the bottom. tBoth are equaly stericly hindered because your side chains can freely rotate.

Comment: @Inselino Depends on whether there is a hydride migration. That would racemize the current stereocenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the reaction proceeds as @Inselino suggests, a secondary carbocation **2** would be formed. Addition of chloride at this point would give a mixture of optically active, diastereomeric chlorides. Further hydride migration forms the achiral carbocation **3**, which leads to racemic chloride **4**. If **1** and **2** are formed reversibly, deuterium may be washed out of the product.
[image]